# Xcode: Why can't I have duplicate ivars in a project? getting duplicate symbols error

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I never noticed this in Xcode before but I'm getting this error when I tried to reuse the same name ivar. I created a simple project with 2 ViewControllers and both of them have the ivar name.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

NSString *name;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    name = @"me";

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end

#import "ViewController2.h"

@interface ViewController2 ()

@end

@implementation ViewController2

NSString *name;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    name = @"Me";

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

when I run the project I get this error:

```
duplicate symbol _name in:
    /Users/cta/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testDuplicate2-cxeetzeptbwtewfecgmoonzgzeyl/Build/Intermediates/testDuplicate2.build/Debug-iphoneos/testDuplicate2.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ViewController.o
    /Users/cta/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testDuplicate2-cxeetzeptbwtewfecgmoonzgzeyl/Build/Intermediates/testDuplicate2.build/Debug-iphoneos/testDuplicate2.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ViewController2.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your implementation `name` is not an instance variable, it is a global. The fact that you place its declaration inside the `@implementation` block does not make it an instance variable.

If you want to make `name` an instance variable, declare it as part of your class extension, like this:

```
@interface ViewController2 () {
    NSString *name;
}
@end
```

Note that if you needed `name` to be `static`, your approach would have worked, because `static` variables are "hidden" from the liner.